# What is the difference between a 2011 i5, and a more recent i5?

Tags: macbook-pro, processor

I am looking at my daughter's MBP.  It is circa 2010/2011, and has a 2.4 i5. Why are processors today called the same name, but are advertised with slower clock speeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So lets compare the i5 family of CPU on MBP.

The i5 is a brand name for a family of processor, that is why is it still called i5.

Core i5" 2.4 13-Inch (Late 2011) features a 32 nm "Sandy Bridge" 2.4 GHz Intel "Core i5" processor (2435M), with two independent processor "cores" on a single silicon chip with a 3 MB shared level 3 cache.

The [2015 MBP](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715?viewlocale=en_CA&locale=en_CA) has up to 2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor (Turbo Boost up to 3.3GHz) with 3MB shared L3 cache.

Based on this alone the 2015 model is >30% faster.

Comment: Thanks for that. In the old days, we labelled each processor differently. We had the 68000, the 68010, 68030, and of course 8008, 80186, 80286, etc. I'm trying to understand the rationale (similarities?), that allow modern processors to keep the same basic name, even as you describe the differences. Is this just a marketing thing?

Comment: ps. I modded you up. Wish  I could add a couple more. This (at least to me), is important stuff.

Comment: Thanks David, yep I know in the good old days it was more clear what one is dealing with.

Comment: Could you give more details please ? is it like turbo boost is the nominal performance of the processor which is underclock for battery purpose ? I'd like to understand what's the difference between my late-2011 with 16Gb ram and ssd and a brand new MBP